# nvidia-settings - "Failed to connect to Mir" - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia-settings

When I attempt to run *nvidia-settings* I get the following error message that does not make any sense to me nor does a web search yield any relevant information:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

What does this mean? what is **Mir**? why isn't *nvidia-settings* working?

Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mir is the next-gen graphical display server created by Canonical that in the future will sostitute the X server. Actually in Ubuntu 16.04 Mir is not installed by default (need to install unity8-desktop-session-mir package). However Mir (for me at least) is not working properly with Nvidia binary drivers (need to use Nouveau)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem during ssh session to remote desktop ubuntu.
The post in [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024489/linux/nvidia-settings-on-headless-server/post/5216937/) thread worked for me.

```
DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1
```